# Getting Html Entities for all major currencies

Tags: html, unicode, html-entities

Currently i am trying to look for the html entities for all the major currencies , i can easily get for USD , EURO , CAD, AUD and few more but i am having hard time getting entities for all other countries i have Bulgarian Lev (лв) , Chinese Renminbi (¥), Russian Ruble (руб), U.A. Emirates Dirhams (د.إ)

Everytime i enter them in my dropdown they are coming as ? sign , so is there any way around it and yes i am using correct meta charset, just trying to get html entities for them

Thanks

Comment: If the characters come up improperly, you are *not* using the correct character set. HTML entities are a just duct-tape workaround - getting the encodings right would be much better

Comment: this is the current charset i am using  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: okay - are the characters in UTF-8 as well? Is the file they are in encoded as UTF-8? (There's usually a dropdown in your editor's "Save As..." dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters showing up as � in UTF-8 data are an indication that the characters you're using are not proper UTF-8 ones.

This can happen when pasting UTF-8 characters into a HTML file that is ISO-8859-1 encoded, for example (this can be fixed by choosing the right encoding in the IDE or editor used). Another frequent reason is the use of a database connection that isn't UTF-8 all the way through.

If you fix that, you should be fine without needing HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `&euro;` for €, the entities for currencies in HTML 4.01 are `&pound;` for £ and `&yen;` for yen/yuan ¥. See [HTML 4.01 list of entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/entities.html).

(HTML 5 drafts add a long list of entities, but it’s worse than useless – generally not supported by browsers, and it gives you nothing that you could not achieve much safer by using numeric character references.)

For other currencies, you can use numeric character references, such as `&#x20a9;`for the won sign ₩. You just need to identify the character(s) used in the symbol by their Unicode numbers.

Alternatively, and usually better, use the characters directly, using a Unicode-enabled authoring tool, with document encoding properly set to and declared as utf-8. But it *is* possible to use “escapes” for all currency symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can see at http://symbologic.info/currency.htm a very large list of currencies with Country, Currency Unit  Symbol, ISO and HTML Entity Code, HTML Decimal and Hex Code. A smaller list is at http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp

The html page encoding set in the needs to match the encodig of the combobox values (that you can load by ajax). You can set it by meta tag like:

Remember that utf-8 is the default encoding for html 5 and ISO-8859-1 is the default encoding for html 4