# How to handle multilingual MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, unicode

I have a DB which stores usernames, passwords, and basic info. The 'info' however, only stores English characters.

How to store data in different languages, let's say English, French, Russian, Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, etc.? I realized that default collation doesn't support that.

What is the best solution, and how do you guys get around it?

Comment: I tried, still getting weird characters for languages other than english. Do you just set the collation for that particular field, or there more that needs to be done?

Comment: There's more. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544312/getting-html-entities-for-all-major-currencies/8544381#8544381 for a list

Comment: [How to handle Unicode in a web app](http://kunststube.net/frontback)

Answer (score 1):

Change the default collation of the whole database and also of the table(s) to utf8_general_ci.  There is no reason to suffer (with this kind of free form data).

```
ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO utf8
ALTER TABLE tbl CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Read about a few gotchas at the end of [this page](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysqls-character-sets-and-collations-demystified).

Comment: Contrary to popular believe, the *collation* has nothing much to do with the *encoding*!

Comment: In MySQL, the collation is very much bound to the encoding. Setting `COLLATE utf8_something` implies `CHARACTER SET utf8`. In any case to be able to handle the data stored in those UTf-8 columns you need to make sure your application talks UTF-8 over the connection to MySQL, with `SET NAMES 'utf8'` or, where available, better library-specific interfaces (eg PHP's `mysql_set_charset` or python-mysql's `charset` constructor argument).